# Display processing message in jQuery DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

**EDIT :**
I want to use the default processing message feature provided by datatables but looks like it works only with server side processing. I am not using server side processing.

---

**Original Question :**
I want to display processing message in [DataTables](http://datatables.net/) whenever I am adding / deleting records from DataTables. I am not using server side processing, depending on few events I delete / add records to DataTables.

I tried using `bProcessing` as `true` and `sProcessing` to give custom progress message **but looks like it works only with server side processing**. How can I achieve same with without server side processing? How can I explicitly call a function which displays processing message?

Here is a similar [example](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/jsonp.html) but it uses server side processing.

Thanks.

---

**Solution :**
[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ajinkya_Parakh/TNe37/5/embedded/result/)
Thanks @Robodude.

Comment: You could try adding event handlers for the different actions that would trigger the message to be displayed. Much like the example here: http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/advanced_init/events_live.html

Comment: @Robodude: I want to display default progress message given by datatables. Showing progress message in alert will not a good idea. I checked available functions and couldnt find out function which displays progress message. Please check example I have mentioned in question, I am looking for the same.

Comment: So I firebugged the example and there is a hidden div on the page that contains the "Processing..." text and the way I imagine display of it is controlled is right before the ajax for the server processing is sent, it shows it and when it's completed, it hides it. I would check to see if you have a default hidden div on your table when enabling bProcessing and control its visibility when the conditions for it appearing are met.

Comment: The id of the hidden div should be the ID.OF.YOUR.TABLE_processing

Comment: @Robodude: Thanks man. Can you please post this as a answer. [If you want some points :) ]

Comment: @Karna: Demo link is not working, can you fix that please? I'm in a same situation and looking for a solution.

Comment: @AbuHamzah: I have corrected it..

Comment: Thanks for the correct link and I'm trying to implement similar but no avail, please have a look at my question I posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27339815/displaying-processing-message-when-clicks-datatables-jquery

Answer (score 21, accepted):

So I firebugged the example and there is a hidden div on the page that contains the "Processing..." text and the way I imagine display of it is controlled is right before the ajax for the server processing is sent, it shows it and when it's completed, it hides it. I would check to see if you have a default hidden div on your table when enabling bProcessing and control its visibility when the conditions for it appearing are met.

The id of the hidden div should be the ID.OF.YOUR.TABLE_processing

So now I'd create handlers for the different conditions that you need to account for much like the examples seen here:

http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/advanced_init/events_live.html