# DataTables Processing Info does not show up

Tags: css, jquery-ui, datatables, server-side

I included my server-side processing DataTables in jQuery UI TABS but after integration the processing info does not show up anymore :(
This [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11311505/display-processing-message-in-jquery-datatables) post writes something about a hidden "Processing..."-Div.
Is it possible that my case matches a "z-index" problem?

This is the DataTables code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "ajax_ssp_class.php",
            "type": "GET"
        },
        "order": [ [0,'asc'] ],
        "paging":true,
        "pagingType": "simple_numbers",
        "pageLength": 50,
        "lengthMenu": [[50, 100, 250, -1], [50, 100, 250, "All"]],
        "lengthChange": true
    } );
});
```

The proof whether the div is existent is tested as true:

```
<div id="example_processing" class="dataTables_processing" style="display: block; z-index: 10000;">Processing...</div>
```

**THE SOLUTION**
I added the following line to the pre-drawing. Now it works.

```
"fnPreDrawCallback":function(){
    //alert("Pre Draw");
    $('#example_processing').attr('style', 'font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; padding-bottom: 60px; display: block; z-index: 10000 !important');
}
```

Comment: Try `$('.dataTables_processing').css("visibility","visible");`

Comment: ensure 'serverSide' is spelled in the exact same case. I had missed it and faced the same issue.

Answer (score 18):

I had a similar problem with the processing text not showing up when using server-side processing and then using search, re-order or changing the page size. The fix was to add the following CSS...

```
<style type="text/css">
    .dataTables_processing {
        top: 64px !important;
        z-index: 11000 !important;
    }
</style>
```

The key things here were the z-Index and top.

This also depends on having

```
"processing": true,
```

in your datatables initialisation

Comment: This is the solution

Comment: thank you so much, i have been searching for this solution hours

Answer (score 13):

1. The ‘processing‘ option needs to be set to true
   and
2. In the ‘sDom‘ option the letter ‘r‘ was needed.

After making the amends, the final code looked something like so:

```
var options = {  
    "sDom": 'prtp',  
    "processing": true,  
    "serverSide": true,  
    "ajax": "/path/to/my/ajax.php"  
}  
var oTable = $('.datatables').dataTable(options);
```

Comment: I had to combine Repton's z-index solution with the "sDom" option.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have an element `$('.dataTables_processing')`.

If it's available then try setting `z-index` to very high value and show it:

```
$('.dataTables_processing').css({"display": "block", "z-index": 10000 })
```

Do that in browser console.

Comment: The element exists, proofed by $('.dataTables_processing').length. But it is not shown...(tested with your z-index)

Comment: You need to find where is this element using **browser dev tools**. The element you are looking for maybe out of the screen or `z-index` is still not big enough.

Comment: I am not that deep minded in debugging. Could you please give an example for firebug besides your mentioned proof of existing div?

Comment: I prefer **Chrome dev tools** https://developer.chrome.com/devtools#dom-and-styles. Run `$('.dataTables_processing')` in console, then right-click on the result and pick `Reveal...`. When you hover the mouse over the element in DOM, it should be highlighted on the page